# How to get localTarget in listener in polymer dart 1.0?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

As I suppose the most safe way of using events target (due to event retargeting) is to obtain normalized `localTarget` or `rootTarget`, which implies that usefulness of `Event.target` is quite limited. Am I right? 
So in every listener that wants to use target data I have to do:

```
onTap(Event ev, [_]){
    var target = Polymer.dom(convertToJs(ev)).localTarget;
    [...]
}
```

Are there any shorthands for this?

Comment: I don't think so. I guesse `convertToJs()` shouldn't be necessary and is an oversight that will be fixed.

Comment: Have you actually tried without `convertToJs()`?

Comment: Yes, and it throws exception (in rc2).

Comment: Does it throw with or without `convertToJs()` or both?

Comment: It throws only without `convertToJs()`, I can't check now what was exactly cause of exception but with `convertToJs()` evertything works fine.

Comment: See also https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/624

Comment: Filed https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_interop/issues/28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in the most recent polymer_interop version: `1.0.0-rc.2`